# Is JSF really ready for a high performance social network project?

Tags: java, performance, jsf, scalability

I have heard a lot of good about JSF but as far as I know people also had lots of serious complains with this technology in the past, not aware of how much the situation has improved. We are considering JSF as a probable technology for a social network project. But we are not aware of the performance scores of JSF neither we could really come across any existing high performance website that had been using JSF. People complain that it is too slow & about its scalability issues.

We are still not very sure if we are doing the right thing by choosing jsf & thus would like to hear from you all about this & take your inputs into consideration. As for the backend we are going with a NoSQL database.

Comment: I have created a quit complex jsf based social app and for me personaly the only thing that limits me is the back end and not the jsf primefaces implementation. I have some performance problems in terms of database transactions but thats because iam not a back end profesional developer.

Answer (score 4):

It's just my opinion, but **high performance** social networks usually need a great deal of client side code tuning, something that can give you a headache if you try to do it twith jsf. JSF is about reusability of components and abstracting black magic like javascript, ajax, resource loading etc, from developer and sometimes makes access to internals of the components difficult.

Comment: I would recommend using php for this purpose

Comment: Why? Java can handle this equally well, if not better. Still probably any action driven framework (Spring MVC?) is a better choice than JSF, since it's easier to control of what gets sent to the server and when. Trying to control that in JSF would be against the idea of JSF.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend JSF.  The last time I saw it was three years ago.  You could time the page loading time for a simple app with a sundial.

Admittedly, a JSF junkie would say that the folks who did it weren't skilled.  But I'd wonder why it's possible to use such a thing so badly.

I would recommend a service-based REST architecture that used a clean UI based on HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript.  I'd implement the former with Spring and the latter with Velocity view or jQuery templates.